# How to hide/show helper messages in form validation with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have included `ngMessages` into my AngularJS application to do some form validation. It's pretty useful, however I've came across something that I can't really understand.

Let's say I have this code inside my Form that is named: `testForm`

```
<input type="text" name="test1" class="form-control" ng-model="test1" required>

<span class="help-block" ng-hide="testForm.test1.$error">Please enter the a test name</span>

<div ng-messages="testForm.test1.$error" ng-if="testForm.test1.$dirty">
    <div class="text-danger" ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the helper message when there is an error in this textbox EXCEPT if the user hasn't started to type anything yet (on `$dirty`).

How is this possible? With this above code my `testForm.test1.$error` always gives me `true` value even if it's empty, therefore always hiding it.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I'm clarifying more what I want to achieve:

- when typing, the helper message should be visible and the error message should be hidden
- when there is an error, the helper message should be hidden and the error message should be visible
- when nothing is touched yet, the helper message should be visible and the error message should be hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `ng-hide="testForm.test1.$error && testForm.test1.$dirty"`? That way the message always displays when the input field is clean (not dirty).

---

Edit:
As far as I see it, you want the message to be visible when input field has focus.

In your controller, initialize `hasFocus` to false:

```
$scope.hasFocus = false;
```

In your HTML file:

```
<input type="text" name="test1" class="form-control" ng-model="test1" 
  ng-focus="hasFocus=true" ng-blur="hasFocus=false" required>

<span class="help-block" ng-hide="!hasFocus && testForm.test1.$error && testForm.test1.$dirty">Please enter the a test name</span>

<div ng-messages="testForm.test1.$error" ng-if="testForm.test1.$dirty">
    <div class="text-danger" ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
</div>
```

You can replace `ng-hide` as follows if it suits you. It will hide the message when `test1` is not empty and when it has error.

```
ng-hide="!hasFocus && testForm.test1.$error && test1"
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. The issue with this is that the message disappears when they start typing something there. It should still remain there. Any ideas for that?

Comment: The only possible error is for "required" right? So when they type something, `$error` should be false. In that case the message would be displayed.

Comment: Yeah the basic problem is that the $error won't be false. It remains true for some reason while it's an empty object.

Comment: Do you mean you want the message to be visible after typing something and then clearing them out? Can you show us a screenshot because I don't think I understand your problem.

Comment: Updated my original post.